# opencart website not rendering correctly outside localhost

Tags: opencart

This is how the website looks outside localhost:

[image]

This is in localhost working perfectly:

[image]

I'm not sure if it could be a problem with using php8 or what else I can check?

SSL is working.

Please, let me know if there's any useful information missing so I can edit and improve the question.

Comment: Enable the developer tools on the browser, and you should see what are the errors in Networking tab

Comment: ok just figured out after checking with developer tools that config.php was pointing to localhost so it wasn't able to load resources, thank you

Comment: please upload your admin/config.php and config.php files. for the better understanding for us.

Comment: Do you have SSL or not?

Comment: its solved as I said in my latest comment